# how to configure a pod to use both hostNetwork and cni's network

Tags: kubernetes, networking

is it possible to run a pod on both hostNetwork and cni's network such that the pod has both the ip's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multus CNI is [capable](https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/blob/master/README.md) of doing exactly that using `NetworkAttachmentDefinition` CRD. It also should be possible to use other CNI plugins together with Multus acting as a meta-plugin, but that should be tested. See [example](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/5199) with Calico+Multus.